# ¿Por qué este módulo no devuelve exactamente el numero racional que calcula?

Tags: java, algoritmos

```
//Este modulo recibe por parametro una variable tipo Racional y la simplifica.
//Primero se calcula el mcd (euclides) y luego se procede a simplificar, el problema surge cuando debo retornar el valor simplificado.

 public Racional simplificar(Racional r) {
    //a=147 y b=686.
    int a = r.getNumerador(), b = r.getDenominador(),resto;
    Racional nuevoRac;
    do {
        resto = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = resto;
    } while (resto != 0);
    //El mcd es 49.
    nuevoRac=new Racional (r.getNumerador()/a,r.getDenominador()/a);
//Aquí r.getNumerador()/a devuelve: 3 y r.getDenominador()/a devuelve 14.
//El problema surge cuando la variable "nuevoRac" toma el valor: 14/14, es decir: 
//el denominador se repite arriba y abajo.
    return nuevoRac;
}
```

Comment: No se cual es el posible error que crees tengas pues acabo de compilar tu codigo y funciona perfectamente bien. No veo la manera en que **r.getNumerador()/a** de 14 y que **r.getDenominador()/a** de 14 tambien, pues el mcd funciona bien y en caso de que **a = b** el resultado es 1/1. Si hay algo mas te sugiero que edites la pregunta.Salu2 .